# How to calculate Tanh in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql

I need to implement Tanh calculation on my procedure. I tried to find formula, but natively and not available on any forums. Kindly help me on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very long time since I did any maths like this, but I believe

```
Tanh(x) = (EXP(x) - EXP(-x)) / (EXP(x) + EXP(-x))
```

Comment: My pleasure. Glad to have helped